# How can I add face to collection auto using python ( AWS Rekognition )?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, image-uploading, face-recognition, auto

I try to build Face-Rekognition using AWS. So, i want to upload file to S3 Bucket only and it uploads from S3 to Collection auto using Python. Pls help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an [Amazon S3 Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) that **triggers an AWS Lambda function** when a new object is uploaded to an Amazon S3 bucket.

The AWS Lambda function can make an [`index_faces()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rekognition.html#Rekognition.Client.index_faces) call to AWS Rekognition to detect faces in the input image and **add them to the specified collection**.

You should first create the Face Collection where the faces will be added. It is also useful to provide an `ExternalImageID` with each image so that the face can be associated with an identifier within your application. This ID will then be returned with future face-search results.

Comment: Please create a new question with details of what you were doing when you received the error.